# Unable to locate button element using selenium webdriver

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I have been trying to locate a nested button element (`<button class="dwnload_xls"`) and click it but have failed to do so. Can someone please help me with this?
I have already tried to use the following(separately) but all of them just give the same response:

> Unable to locate element

My code:

```
frame = WebDriverWait(browser, 30).until(lambda x: x.find_element_by_xpath(".//*[contains(@class, 'downloadxlsform')]//div[contains(@class,'downloadform')]//button[contains(@class, 'dwnload_xls')]"))
```

HTML code:

```
<form action="/bdataservlet" class="downloadxlsform" method="GET" name="downloadxlsform">
<div class="downloadform" name="downloadform">
<div class="sub_title">All traded products</div>
<input id="methodxls" name="method" type="hidden" value="InstrumentList"><input name="profileid" type="hidden" value="1124"><button class="dwnload_xls" name="SUBMIT" onclick="this.form.submit()" style="background-image:url(/sites/bet/images/english/download_xls_eng_white.gif)" type="submit"></button>
</div>
</form>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can let selenium find the button and submit the form via [`submit()`](http://selenium-python.readthedocs.org/api.html#selenium.webdriver.remote.webelement.WebElement.submit):

```
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC

form = WebDriverWait(driver, 30).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "form.downloadxlsform")))
form.submit()
```

Also, if the form is inside an `iframe` you need to [switch to it first](http://selenium-python.readthedocs.org/api.html#selenium.webdriver.remote.webdriver.WebDriver.switch_to_frame):

```
driver.switch_to.frame('frame_name')
```